# Java String.subsequence() method

Tags: java

Say, String str = "hello world" ;
To, get hello, we can use str.subSequence(0, 5). 
If it's a 0-based indexed string, then why we don't write str.subSequence(0.4) as 'o' has the index 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the javadoc for the method.

```
public CharSequence subSequence(int beginIndex,int endIndex)
```

Returns a new character sequence that is a subsequence of this sequence.
An invocation of this method of the form

```
 str.subSequence(begin, end)
```

behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation

```
 str.substring(begin, end)
```

This method is defined so that the String class can implement the CharSequence interface.

Specified by:
subSequence in interface CharSequence

Parameters:
**beginIndex** - the begin index, inclusive.
**endIndex** - the end index, exclusive.

Returns:
the specified subsequence.

Throws:
**IndexOutOfBoundsException** - if beginIndex or endIndex are negative, if endIndex is greater than length(), or if beginIndex is greater than startIndex

Answer (score 2):

The first argument value is inclusive whereas the second one is exclusive.

Comment: As specified in [the javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#subSequence%28int,%20int%29)

Answer (score 0):

It actually has nothing to do the "0-ness" at all. The API is clear about this and gives an example.

Substring and subSequence will return the set of characters of the set [n, m-1]. Or in other words, every character in the substring except for the 5th character, or more concretely, characters 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4.

That way you could do:

substring(offset,length+offset); notice how hello is 5 letters long?

(Corrected now).

Comment: [n, m-1) isn't correct. Either [n, m) or [n, m-1]. Also, the second argument isn't the length.

Comment: Yes, this part is incorrect.  What it does allow you to do is to extract a string `LENGTH` characters long by using `...substring(offset, offset+LENGTH)`  Having the end index exclusive actually eliminates a lot of `-1`s that would litter the code.

Answer (score 0):

Here in this methos **subSequence() or SubStribg()**, The second variable is not zero-based.So we have to calculate until **secondvariable-1**.